# Read all rows and display them in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get all rows from SQLite database and display them in a ListView. And I'm having trouble returning the list with all values. The database was pre-created and is now in the /raw folder.

Table (FTSgesla_content):

```
ID     Value1         Value3
1      Some text1     Some text1
2      Some text2     Some text2
```

This is my code:

```
public class GeslaPodatkovnaBaza 
{
    private static final String TAG = "GeslaPodatkovnaBaza";

    public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
    public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gesla";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSgesla";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
    private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context The Context within which to work, used to create the DB
     */
    public GeslaPodatkovnaBaza(Context context) {
        mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public GeslaPodatkovnaBaza createDatabase() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDatabaseOpenHelper.createDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public GeslaPodatkovnaBaza open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDatabaseOpenHelper.openDataBase();
            mDatabaseOpenHelper.close();
            mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDatabaseOpenHelper.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAllWords()
    {
        return mDatabaseOpenHelper.getAll();
    }

    private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() 
    {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
        map.put(KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_DEFINITION);
        map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
                BaseColumns._ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
        return map;
    }

    public Cursor getWord(String rowId, String[] columns) 
    {
        String selection = "rowid = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

        /* This builds a query that looks like:
         *     SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE rowid = <rowId>
         */
    }

    public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) 
    {
        //String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
        String selection = FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " MATCH ?"; //išče tudi po opisih
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
    }

    private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
        /* The SQLiteBuilder provides a map for all possible columns requested to
         * actual columns in the database, creating a simple column alias mechanism
         * by which the ContentProvider does not need to know the real column names
         */
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {

        private final Context mHelperContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

        private static String DB_PATH="/data/data/com.example.enigmar/databases/";
        private static String DB_NAME="gesla";


        DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.mHelperContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {

        }

        //THIS IS THE FUNCTION
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAll()
        {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> item;// = new HashMap<String, String>();

            String stavekSQL = "SELECT c0suggest_text_1, c1suggest_text_2 FROM FTSgesla_content ORDER BY c0suggest_text_1 ASC";
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_NAME;
            Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(stavekSQL, null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    item.put("line1", cursor.getString(0));
                    Log.e("ListIzBaze", "dodalBesedo1");
                    item.put("line2", cursor.getString(1));
                    Log.e("ListIzBaze", "dodalBesedo2");
                    list.add(item);
                }
                while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            Log.e("ListIzBaze", "VracamList");
            return list;
            //return mDatabase.execSQL(stavekSQL);
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException
        {

            boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();

            if(!mDataBaseExist)
            {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                this.close();
                try 
                {
                    copyDataBase();
                    Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
                } 
                catch (IOException mIOException) 
                {
                    throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
                }
            }

        }

        private boolean checkDataBase()
        {

            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            return dbFile.exists();

        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
        {

            //InputStream mInput = mHelperContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();

            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            InputStream mInput = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.gesla);

            byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int mLength;
             while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
             {
                 mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
             }
             mOutput.flush();
             mOutput.close();
             mInput.close();

            }

        public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
        {

            String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            return mDatabase != null;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

        if(mDatabase != null)
            mDatabase.close();

        super.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what u try for listview ?

Comment: what do you mean by having trouble? what happens as a result? a crash? listview remains empty? nothing is returned from the database? what?

Comment: Download one sample Example like this http://www.4shared.com/rar/9aFDUytU/SimpleDatabaseExa.html?

Comment: It creates the database (looking at LogCat) and then the debugger view opens (no errors in LogCat). It opens ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(...) and says "Source not found."

Comment: Problem is I'm using the SearchableDictionary example, and it's not created in the same way as other tutorials.

Comment: Basically, the problem is returning the cursor from the database to main activity (SearchableDictionary in this example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/SearchableDictionary.htm)

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't see where you open database connection, in DiccionaryHelper?, because i saw that you use database here `Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(stavekSQL, null);` I use a static instance of `SQLiteDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

**TO MAKE THE LISTVIEW IN ANDROID**:

•   First, We have to store all those values in list view. For that purpose we are using List function.

•   Then, We have to set those list value in one List array Adapter.

•   you, should extends activity into list activity.

•   make sure that in the main.xml you have a ListView element with the id @android:id/list.

**FUNCTION:**

```
       List<String[].
```

•   setListAdapter.

```
     Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from sv_tb_fieldnotes where sv_fieldnote_created_by_fk='" + get_userid + "'",null);
     List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

         c.moveToFirst();
         while(!c.isAfterLast())
         {
             title=new String[]{c.getString(3),c.getString(0)};
             list.add(title);
             c.moveToNext(); 
         }      

     c.close();
     db.close();
     fetch_fieldnote_title=new String[list.size()]; 
     fetch_fieldnote_id=new String[list.size()]; 
            int x=0;
            String assigning_fetch_fieldnote_title;
            String assigning_fetch_fieldnote_id;
            for (String[] name : list) {
                assigning_fetch_fieldnote_title =name[0];
                assigning_fetch_fieldnote_id=name[1];
                fetch_fieldnote_title[x]=assigning_fetch_fieldnote_title;
                fetch_fieldnote_id[x]=assigning_fetch_fieldnote_id;
                x++;
            }

            //To generate the list view.
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fetch_fieldnote_title));
 }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(this, stg1[position], 2000).show();
    fetch_title=fetch_fieldnote_title[position];
    fetch_id=fetch_fieldnote_id[position];
    //To register the list view with context menu.
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
```

Comment: I know how to make and use ListView. The problem is not in ListView it's in returning the values to ListView.

Comment: See the comments of my post.

Comment: make sure that in the main.xml you have a ListView element with the id @android:id/list.